# How to connect SQL Server with Rstudio?

Tags: r, sql-server, database

I have downloaded Microsoft SQL Server on my Mac with the Docker image as described  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-docker?view=sql-server-ver15&pivots=cs1-bash), and also I have downloaded the database AdventureWorks2019 as an example which I found it [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/samples/adventureworks-install-configure?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=ssms).

So far so good. Everything works fine.

Now I want to import this database in my RStudio.

I followed the instructions which I found [here](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/drivers/).

So I opened RStudio and I typed the following:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), 
                      Driver = "SQL Server", 
                      Server = "localhost", 
                      Database = "AdventureWorks2019",
                      uid = "sa",
                      pwd = "<YourStrong@Passw0rd>",
                      port = 1433,
                      Trusted_Connection = "True")
```

I get an error

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'SQL Server' : file not found

Meanwhile the container in Docker is active and the localhost is active (green) in MS SQL.
I searched on the web for similar errors on Mac and I am more confused.

Any help? Someone?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misreading your question, but there seem to be a few issues here... 1) `Trusted_Connection = "true"` is used for Windows/Kerberos authentication, use that, or use `uid="sa", pwd="<YourString@Passw0rd>"`, but don't mix the two. 2) if you're trying to "import" the AdventureWorks2019 database then it doesn't already exist on the instance and you won't be able to establish a connection with `Database = "AdventureWorks2019"` ... try `master` instead. 3) Finally, the error message suggests that you haven't configured an `SQL Server` driver in `odbcinst.ini` or `odbc.ini` yet.

Comment: Check `odbc::odbcListDrivers()`: of the available choices, if you only see `"SQL Server"`, then you very likely need to upgrade to something in the last decade, as that's a very old driver. Ideally, you'd be seeing `"ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server"*, which is the most recent version.

Comment: @r2evans I see nothing is empty.I trying to install a new DSN via ODBC Manager app but the app does not show the freetds that I have installed with home-brew.It's a mess for Mac.Totally a mess.

Comment: Homebrew and R are not typically best of friends; I don't have a mac so I cannot really help much there. Most advise on SO on questions that start with "mac" and "homebrew" usually say "don't use homebrew".

Comment: `!!:gs/advise/advice/` ;-)

Comment: @r2evans on windows though it’s straightforward and very simple to connect sql server and r studio.

Comment: If you cannot see the freetds driver when you call `odbcListDrivers`, then freetds is not installed correctly, regardless of OS or homebrew.

Comment: @r2evans any site for proper instruction of how i correctly install freetds?

Comment: FreeTDS on Windows? I found back-channels to the daily build for their CI testing, got an artifact and I got it to install ... and those proved unstable (memory leaks) in my experience, and I've tried several times (though not in the last few months). I'm able to work with the official [mssqlodbc17](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), and ever since the `odbc` package implemented column-ordering workarounds to bugs in MS's ODBC drivers, it's been working like a champ (for me), both linux and windows.

Comment: No freetds for Mac.On windows odbc works just fine

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(
  odbc::odbc(),
  Driver   = "SQL Server",
  Server   = "server",
  Database = "database",
  UID      = "uid",
  PWD      = "pwd"
)
```

I don't think you need `Port` and `Trusted_Connection`?